# What are these timestamps and how can i decode them?

Tags: php, timestamp, decode

I have a bunch of timestamps that i need to sort and compare.

They look like this:

```
AAAAAIi1o0A=
AAAAAIlhrNQ=
AAAAAIljIZg=
AAAAAIlkA+E=
```

The part providing the data tells me that they are 8 byte timestamps of the type "TimeStamp".

I am unsure what these are formatted as and how to decode them using php.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Ghost :-)

Comment: Unix timestamps (what one would usually mean when talking about a timestamp) are an 8 byte integer value of seconds since midnight on 1/1/1970 and are often written in either decimal (for human viewing) or binary (for storage). It looks like these have been converted for an unknown reason into ASCII. However the values you have posted are 12 bytes. I'd find out which 8 bytes actually represent the timestamp (I'd suspect removing the first 4 would do it) and convert the ascii values back to decimal

Comment: Actually I will correct myself, it's too early in the morning :) A timestamp should be 4 bytes... but it is possible these are including fractional (decimal) parts for more accuracy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after writing my comments I gave it a try and got some useful (realistic) dates out of these.

Here is what I did...

I figured each value you have is 12 bytes, I discarded the first 4 bytes, took the second 4 bytes as the whole date/time, followed by 3 bytes of fractional seconds (also discarded) and the final byte I will assume is a delimiter since it is too much of a coincidence for my liking for the last byte of a fractional second value to be the same on all of them

Each section of bytes I first converted from ASCII to binary then concatenated the 4 8-bit binary values into a single 32-bit value, then converted that into a decimal, which represented the number of seconds after midnight on 1/1/1970

As such, I got the following values

```
Thu, 16 Sep 2004 11:21:37
Thu, 16 Sep 2004 11:35:20
Thu, 16 Sep 2004 11:35:22
Thu, 16 Sep 2004 11:35:23
```

Comment: This looks very promising, except for the year. (But I can compensate for that)
I will test if the data checks out on this and return.
Thank you very much.